# How to take only the array matrix (item) from np.array()

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a list `mask_arr` of numpy array and the element of list is numpy array like this:

```
mask_arr[0][:]
array([[255, 255, 255, ..., 255, 255, 255],
       [255, 255, 255, ..., 255, 255, 255],
       [255, 255, 255, ..., 255, 255, 255],
       ...,
       [255, 255, 255, ..., 255, 255, 255],
       [255, 255, 255, ..., 255, 255, 255],
       [255, 255, 255, ..., 255, 255, 255]], dtype=uint8)
```

How to take only the 2D array without the `dtype` part:

```
[[255, 255, 255, ..., 255, 255, 255],
 [255, 255, 255, ..., 255, 255, 255],
 [255, 255, 255, ..., 255, 255, 255],
 ...,
 [255, 255, 255, ..., 255, 255, 255],
 [255, 255, 255, ..., 255, 255, 255],
 [255, 255, 255, ..., 255, 255, 255]]
```

the reason is that I am getting the following error:

```
im = mask_arr[i]
*** TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

Comment: It's not possible to remove the `dtype`, that is fundamental component of the array. Can you explain what `i` is? From the error message it is apparently an array since you cannot index a list with an array.

Comment: @RoySmart `i` is the index of for loop

Comment: can you post the rest of your code? From the error message it seems like `i` is an array, not a single integer.

Comment: @RoySmart thanks for mentioning the point. I could correct it

Answer (score 0):

Make a list of arrays:

```
In [19]: alist = [np.ones((3,4),'uint8'),np.zeros((2,2),'int16')]
```

default display of that list:

```
In [20]: alist
Out[20]: 
[array([[1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1]], dtype=uint8),
 array([[0, 0],
        [0, 0]], dtype=int16)]
```

Display the elements of the list using the `str` method:

```
In [21]: for a in alist: print(str(a))
[[1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1]]
[[0 0]
 [0 0]]
```

The 'array', `dtype` and commas are omit.  That's just a display style; no change in the actual arrays.

Compare that with the display of the arrays converted to lists - note the commas.

```
In [22]: for a in alist: print(a.tolist())
[[1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1]]
[[0, 0], [0, 0]]
```

In python, each class has defined `__str__` and `__repr__` methods, which determine how they are displayed.  The display gives an idea of the object's class.  But different displays don't change the class.

Likewise each class has its own indexing rules.